# iPhone simulator (detect different device simulators)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

With the upcoming release of the iPhone X, I want to be able to display a different UI layout for the iPhone X (due to round corners and bottom line, which kinda works as the home button replacement).

I am using the following nuget package to retrieve the model information:
https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model

It works perfectly fine, but all the different simulators (iPhone 7, 8, X) only come up as Simulator.

Is there a way to differentiate between the different iPhone Simulators in code within my Xamarin mobile app?

Many thanks,
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the simulator is a weird animal, the screen size is as good as any other test after the other tests for iOS version and the availability of FaceID on a physical device:

```
public bool iPhoneX()
{
    var version = new Version(ObjCRuntime.Constants.Version);
    if (version < new Version(11, 0))
        return false;
    if (ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch == ObjCRuntime.Arch.DEVICE)
    {
        using (var context = new LocalAuthentication.LAContext())
        {
            if (context.BiometryType == LABiometryType.TypeFaceId)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (UIScreen.MainScreen.PreferredMode.Size.Height == 2436)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or an optimized property for repeated (binding) calls:

```
static bool? iPhoneX;
public bool isPhoneX
{
    get
    {
        if (iPhoneX == null)
        {
            if (new Version(ObjCRuntime.Constants.Version) < new Version(11, 0))
                iPhoneX = false;
            else
            {
                if (ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch == ObjCRuntime.Arch.DEVICE)
                {
                    using (var context = new LocalAuthentication.LAContext())
                    {
                        iPhoneX = context.BiometryType == LABiometryType.TypeFaceId;
                    }
                }
                else
                    iPhoneX = UIScreen.MainScreen.PreferredMode.Size.Height == 2436;
            }
        }
        return (bool)iPhoneX;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2118781 thanks, I added the cached property version that I have in a prototype that I am building as I am binding on that property within a UITableView (kind-of like the scrolling demo that bumps elements away from the notch when in landscape mode)

Comment: While this does "work", I recommend not doing this in most cases. It is a great way to introduce subtle (or not so subtle) bugs and introduce compatibility problems on future hardware. Relying on the model identifier or hard-coding specific screen sizes is asking for trouble in the general case.

Comment: @russbishop If you look at the logic fall-thru, the screen size is only used if the device is a "simulator" in order to determine if it is an `iPhoneX` simulator or not, the hardware capabilities are used if it is an actual device.

Comment: I know, I just want to warn people off using screen-size checks and the like because *most* uses of it are a bad idea. Do note that you can get the actual model identifier with ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] which is always `iPhone10,3` for the iPhoneX Simulator... which is also a bad idea in most cases (though not all). Most of the time people should use Safe Area Layout Guide because that will be correct for current and future hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the [Safe Area Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area) which will automatically increase the top/bottom margin on the iPhone X.

Comment: Thanks ekscrypto, but regardless of this; Is there a way to identify the differentiate the iPhone 8 from the iPhone X simulator at all? Other than going by screen size/resolution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you should definitely be using the [Safe Area Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).

If you really really have a need to detect the model then look for the `SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER` environment variable. iPhone X will return `iPhone10,3`.

`let model = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]`